# How to parse a column with minutes to two different ones (one with hour and the other one with minutes)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using mysql and I need a query that solves my problem:
I actually have a column called `length` from a table called `film` that has the number of minutes example: `181`.

And I would like to have two new ones: One that displays the hours `3` and the other one the minutes `1`

I have been trying with "case" but I don't know how to use a value into another that doesn't exist

example 2: column length has `159` and I need to show two columns, the column hours will have `2` and the minutes column `39`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`div` and `mod` operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html) to do integer division and modulo.

```
SELECT *,
       length div 60 hours,
       length mod 60 minutes
       FROM film;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hours = integer portion of minutes/ 60
Minutes =remainder of minutes/60

Mysql has div and module functions

Comment: I know that, but how do I make this column into two brand ones?